# How to combine Javascript arrays and objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

oldArray = [ [{name: xyz}, {name: abc}, {name: def}], [ {name: ghi}, {name: jkl} ] ]

expected

newArray = [ {name: xyz}, {name: abc}, {name: def}, {name: ghi}, {name: jkl} ]

Answer (score 0):

You can [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array

```js
const oldArray = [
  [{ name: "xyz" }, { name: "abc" }, { name: "def" }],
  [{ name: "ghi" }, { name: "jkl" }],
];

const result = oldArray.flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you decpk Its working :)